# Android: Switching activities in swipeable tab layout

Tags: java, android, tabs

In my android app there is a swipeable tab layout. It has two tabs: New Complain and Previous Complains. When click the complain tab I need to start NewComplain.java. Here is my NewComplain class code segment:

**NewComplain** class

```
 public class NewComplain extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int Year;
    private int Month;
    private int Day;
    private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    private View viewLoad;
    private TextView heading, date;
    private Spinner spiComplain, spiProduct;
    private EditText description, contInfo;
    private Button btnDate;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> complainAdapter, prodAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> lstComplain = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> lstProdNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewLoad = LayoutInflater.from(NewComplain.this).inflate(
                R.layout.new_complain, null);
        setContentView(viewLoad);                       
    }
}
```

This id my **TabsPagerAdapter** class.

```
 package xont.virtusel.v4.controller.sale;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:

        case 1:

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }

}
```

And this is my **main activity** class.

```
 package xont.virtusel.v4.controller.sale;

    import xont.virtusel.v4.controller.R;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    public class CustomerComplainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = { "New Complain", "Previous Complains" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

How should I add switching activity statements into this TabsPagerAdapter class. I used intent. But it's not worked.
Can anyone plz be so kind enough to clarify this issue.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your problem?

If you can't start new `Fragment`, try this:
in **TabsPagerAdapter** in `public Fragment getItem()` method

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new NewComplain();
        case 1:
            //return some other class
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and create a constructor for `NewComplain` class

Answer (score 0):

You are adding fragments, not activities.  In your Tab listeners, you are given a FragmentTransaction which you should be using to update which of your fragments is showing with respect to the tab pressed.

Also, don't inflate in fragment on create, do that in on create view.